# How do I build a scalable activity stream or newsfeed using Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, feed

How do I build a scalable activity stream or newsfeed using Meteor?

I'm building a music app with a newsfeed using Meteor. What are the best practices for building a scalable newsfeed using Meteor? I've looked at Mongo, Redis and Cassandra. Tips would be much appreciated.

So far I've found this blogpost which explains how to use Mongo (thank you google translate). (http://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/242593/)

Comment: I'd highly suggest checking out https://getstream.io for what you are looking for. You're going to end up handling a lot of infrastructure in the long run and that can quickly become a massive pain -- downtime, cost, headaches, etc.

Not trying to push a SaaS product offering on you, but it's sometimes better to use a tool that has been proven to work over building your own.

I know off the top of my head that Stream powers feeds for over 50 million end users, with over a billion feed updates per week. Pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Building scalable feed technology is quite complex. A lot of articles have been written about the underlying challenges. Did you see my tutorial about integrating [Stream + Meteor](http://blog.getstream.io/post/136611889848/building-news-feeds-activity-streams-with-meteor)? That's definitely the easiest way.

If you are interested in implementing a Meteor publications that combines documents from different Mongo Collections I recommend the following [article](http://www.meteorimpact.io/content/patterns/timeline.html). This will allow you to create a publication for a news/activity feed which intermingles activities stored in multiple Mongo Collections.

If you really want to implement the storage side of things yourself our open source [Stream-Framework](https://github.com/tschellenbach/stream-framework) has a ton of interesting articles listed on the Github page. Here are some of my favourites:

- [Twitter 2013](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html) Redis based, database fallback
- [Cassandra at Instagram](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/interview/facebooks-instagram-making-the-switch-to-cassandra-from-redis-a-75-insta-savings/)
- [Facebook history](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack)